# Sending Emails within a Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, email, docker, postfix, sendmail

Hello I'm trying to run the following command in my container

```
mail -s "This is Subject" someone@example.com < /path/to/file
```

How should my dockerfile look so the above command can be executed ?

I tried the following solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890011/ubuntu-dockerfile-mailutils-install

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mailutils
```

but I get this error

> The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y mailutils' returned a non-zero code: 100

I also tried some examples like this

https://github.com/42technologies/docker-postfix-gmail

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mailutils
RUN echo "postfix postfix/mailname string gmail.com" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y postfix

ADD mail.sh /mail.sh
RUN chmod +x /mail.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/mail.sh"]
```

But I don't won't the container to only send emails because I'm customizing a specific container and I just want to enable the sending email features.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the mail.sh, only left the enable part.
And when you want to send email out just need to run some command.
e.g #echo "body example" | mailx -s "subject example" someone.email@xx.xx